# Installing .msu patch file with wusa.exe is not working with invoke-command

Tags: powershell-3.0, patch, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am trying to install an windows patch update (`.msu` patch file) with `wusa.exe` to a remote machine using `Invoke-command`. But it is throwing error with return code 5.

Is there any other way to do it with out using `start-process` or not extracting and installing `.cab` file?.

Answer (score 0):

Windows update will not permit you to perform installs over Powershell Remote sessions since it does not allow any remote authentication token.

This is a similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/559287/what-does-wusa-exe-return-code-5-mean

The recommended answer on to the above question is to use PSRemoting to create a scheduled task on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I wrote a function to utilize a scheduled task.  Just needs a few arguments.

I'm not happy passing the admin creds in plain text, however, some updates require these in order to run the scheduled task headless.  Also, I wanted to use this on multiple ephemeral vms, so an encoded set of creds wouldn't work for me.

Oh, and the sleeps may not be needed, but I wanted to make sure it didn't run too fast and catch an incorrect condition.

the tempdir variable is the working directory your executable is in.  Task scheduler requires you to be in the working directory of the executable as it adds a prefix of the working directory to the file path, even if you specify the full file path.

```
#scheduled task wrapper for installing files which normally fail due to 
#windows restrictions on invoke-command
function Use-TaskWrapperInstaller {
    param(
        [string]$ffile,
        [string]$farguments,
        [string]$ftaskname,
        [string]$ftempDir,
        [string]$fadmin,
        [string]$fpassword
    )
    Invoke-Command -Session $Global:s -ScriptBlock {
        $action=$(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$Using:ftempDir\$Using:ffile" -Argument $Using:farguments)
        $principal=$(New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupId "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest)
        $settings=$(New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet)
        $task=(New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $principal -Settings $settings)
        Set-Location "$Using:ftempDir"
        if ($(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Using:ftaskname" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).State -eq "Ready") {
                    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Using:ftaskname" -Confirm:$false
                }
        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Using:ftaskname" -InputObject $task -User "$Using:fadmin" -Password "$Using:fpassword" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
        Start-Sleep -Seconds "2"
        Write-Host "Starting installation task: $Using:ftaskname"
        Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Using:ftaskname"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds "2"
        Do {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds "1"
        } Until ($(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Using:ftaskname" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).State -match "Ready")
        Write-Host "Installation of $Using:ftaskname using Task Wrapper complete."
    }
}
```